# STS4 - No content assist in application.properties

Tags: spring-boot, content-assist, spring-tools-4

Just watched the new Video [Getting Super Productive with Spring Tools 4 and Spring Boot 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tDiK2fTRuJY&t=1125s).
Wanted to test the content assist in `application.properties` under STS4 and it doesn't work.

When I press `ctrl+space` there is nothing.

Tags should be spring-tools-4. But I don't have enough reputation to create it.

Comment: Hard to say what is going wrong here without any more details. Make sure that your project is a Spring Boot project and has resolved the necessary dependencies, so that the tooling can find them. Attaching a sample project might also help to reproduce this issue.

Comment: Works now with STS 4.4.0

Answer (score 6):

This works for me:

1. Right-click on `application*{-yourProfile}*.properties`
2. Open With
3. Other
4. Generic Editor - Spring Properties
5. Click Ok
6. A "Spring-ish" leaf icon will appear besides the file-name and auto-complete/content-assist will now be available.

Answer (score 2):

try to open this properties file as "Generic Editor - Spring properties"

right-click on file > open with> Generic Editor - Spring properties (or "other" if it not displayed in the list)

Answer (score 2):

Go To

Window -> Preferences -> click on Language Servers -> check all rows -> click on apply

Now it should work.

Answer (score 0):

This image response is to support the question, I am facing the same Issue:
Looking for solution.

[image]

App Run fine but we see these red swiggly lines in application.properties file like below
[image]

Preferences
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did anyone figure this out? It looks like I am having the exact same problem with STS 4.1 installed just now. Please help if you know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with my properties/yaml files in STS4. After some researches, I found out, the STS4, uses a language server for code assist/completion which is broken or there is a communication issue with it.

The best solution is to stop using STS4 altogether. Use the more stable version which is STS3 instead.

Update: After I changed the STS's java runtime from 8 to 11 everything fixed.

Answer (score 0):

go to Window -> Preferences (for windows).

Java > Editor > Content Assist : Auto Activation - [checkbox] enable auto activation

Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced : select the proposal types - select the checkbox against "Java Proposals"

That's it.